# How to find the common words between 2 strings and return those sorted

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resolve a dilemma in Javascript. I would like to find the common words between 2 strings. For example, I have the next strings `"hello, world", "hello, earth"` and the common word is `"hello"` and also `"one,two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three" ==> "one,three,two"`

I tried to use thee for loop but not in a classic way but I got issues and I 'm printing the wrong result.

```
const commonWords = (a, b) => {
  const w = [];

  const first = a.split(",");
  const second = b.split(",");

  for (let c in first) {
    if (second, c.length >= 1) {
      w.push(c);
      w.sort();
    }
  }

  return (w);
};

console.log(commonWords("hello,world", "hello,earth"));
```

I would like to understand if my approach is good or there is the best way of doing it

Comment: What is `if (second, c.length >= 1)` supposed to mean? It's equivalen to `if (c.length >= 1)`

Comment: You don't need to sort `w` after every time you push onto it, do that once at the end.

Comment: The correct condition is `if (second.indexOf(c) > -1)`

Comment: I tried the suggestions but I'm getting this `[ '0', '1' ]` instead of the common words

Comment: You should be using `first[c]` not just `c` inside the loop, since `c` is the index.

Comment: I think you want to do `let c of first` instead of `let c in first`. The `c` values the way you have it will be the index of the item in the array, which is why you are getting numbers.

Comment: Also see [why is using for-in with array a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel your approach gave me undefined

Comment: Not sure what else you changed, but I get `["hello", "world"]` when I just change `in` to `of` in your code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const commonWords = (a, b) => {
let w;
let first = a.split(",");
let second = b.split(",");
let temp;

if (second.length > first.length) {temp = second; second = first; first = temp;}
w =  first.filter(function (e) {
    return second.indexOf(e) > -1;
});

return w.sort();
};

console.log(commonWords("one,two,three", "four,five,one,two,six,three"));
```

> ["one", "three", "two"]